# Does anyone know how I can add webcam into my website for Augment Reality?

Tags: video-streaming, webcam, video-encoding, augmented-reality

Does anyone know how I can add web-cam into my website so all my users can print the AR code and view it on my website?

Thanks.

Comment: What platform are you using? Programming language? What AR tech are you using? A bit of detail goes a long way.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need AR techonolgy to print markers... it's enough to save it to an image file or PDF (etc) and let the user print.

To have AR on your site you need to use something like Flash and the FLARToolkit for image recognition and positioning in space.

This video tutorial is a very good starting point: http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=114

Good luck!

Comment: Any idea on how to use Web based AR [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59246892/how-to-do-a-web-based-ar-solution-without-using-apps)